# Yii2: Use NOT EXISTS or NOT IN

Tags: sql, yii2, not-exists, notin

How do I use the conditions "not exist" and "not in" in Yii2?
I have a select with the list of users, but want to exclude users who are on the table "user_post"

User

> id_user | username

User_post

> id_user_post | id_post | id_user

```
 <?= $form->field($model, 'id_user')->dropDownList(
         ArrayHelper::map(User::find()

                ->all(),'id_user','username'),
        ['prompt' => 'Select User']
    ) ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```
User::find()->where(['not in','user_id',[1,2,3]]);
```

Which returns `Users` with ID's not in `[1,2,3]`